# Restrictions on variables?

Tags: php, variables

Are there any restrictions on variable names, for instance the use of $loop or $counter? I seem to be having problems with them not incrementing.

Is there also a difference between something like $i++ and $i += 1 ?

Comment: Post your code that isn't working.

Comment: Very broadly generally: no. Please produce a concrete example of code that "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you using a certain framework? Post code :)

Comment: The code is complex - however I seemed to have solved the issue by changing their names to something like $looplist and $counterlist - I have other variables like $counterorder and $looporder - maybe there was some conflict with the first several letters being the same... not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any restrictions on variable names, for instance the use of $loop or $counter? I seem to be having problems with them not incrementing.

[There are rules for variable names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) but those two do not violate them and are acceptable.

> Is there also a difference between something like $i++ and $i += 1 ?

Fundamentally, no. They both increment $i by 1.